# Ассинхронное программирование. Загрузка с FTP

Tags: c#, wpf, ftp

Доброго времени суток. 
Пытаюсь скачать и поставить изображение в Image.

```
async public void LoadAvatar()
    {
       MainWindow.Instance.AvatarLoadBar.Value += 30;
       byte[] imgbyte = await GetImgByte();
       MainWindow.Instance.AvatarLoadBar.Value += 30;
       Bitmap avatarbit = await ByteToImage(imgbyte);
       MainWindow.Instance.AvatarLoadBar.Value += 40;
       ConvertImage(avatarbit);
     }


async public Task<byte[]> GetImgByte()
    {
        WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient();
        ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*****", "*****");
        byte[] imageByte = await ftpClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(avatar);
        return await Task.FromResult(imageByte);
    }
```

где avatar ссылка на изображение.

```
 async public static Task<Bitmap> ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
        {
            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] pData = blob;
            mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);
            mStream.Dispose();
            return await Task.FromResult(bm);
        }
        public void ConvertImage(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            BitmapSource b = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bmp.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
            MainWindow.Instance.AvatarLoadBar.Visibility =System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

Сделал все что можно асинхронным но ловлю фриз после первого

```
  MainWindow.Instance.AvatarLoadBar.Value += 30;
```

И дальше прогресс бар исчезает и проявляется картинка. Хотелось бы понять почему не могут сработать еще 2

```
  MainWindow.Instance.AvatarLoadBar.Value += 30;
  MainWindow.Instance.AvatarLoadBar.Value += 40;
```

Comment: 1) Предполагаю, что из-за того, что операции по конвертации выполняются очень быстро. Поставьте `await Task.Delay(1500)` после второго и третьего изменения значения `ProgressBar`. 2) Не понял, зачем вызывать `Task.FromResult`, если вам нужно вернуть результат. 3) Метод `ByteToImage` снхронный. Не нужно туда Task прикручивать. 4) Используйте `using` в `ByteToImage`.

Comment: Спасибо всем, все заработало

Comment: Добавление задержки я предложил для того, чтобы подтвердить предположение. Ее не нужно оставлять в готовом коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас только один асинхронный метод, GetImgByte, далее всё выполняется синхронно. Зачем вы везде делаете Task.FromResult? Метод от этого асинхронным не становится, в первом случае это вообще лишнее. В ByteToImage, если хотите его сделать асинхронным, и что бы вернуть управление UI потоку для перерисовки прогресс бара, надо сделать Task.

```
async public Task<byte[]> GetImgByte()
{
    WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient();
    ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*****", "*****");
    return await ftpClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(avatar);
}

async public static Task<Bitmap> ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        using(var mStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] pData = blob;
            mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
            return new Bitmap(mStream, false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Не согласен с методом `ByteToImage`. Он сам по себе синхронный. Имеет смысл его таким и оставить, чтобы была возможность вызвать его синхронно. Если его хочется вызывать асинхронно, то оборачиваем в месте вызова `await Task.Run(() => ByteToImage(bytes)`.